# Python list comprehension error with nested loop

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension

```
patches = [grayimg[i*8:(i+1)*8, j*8:(j+1)*8] for i in range(num_h) for j in range(num_w)]
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Could somebody help me find the error? It is a nested loop, I don't see any error.

Comment: 2nd line is your error line ?

Comment: also what is your 'grayimg' , please add some example

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: Just tried it with generic arrays for `grayimg` and is working fine. Please add more relevant code and also more detail on the exception if possible

Comment: Thank you for paying attention. I found it is syntax error from the code above this line.  This line should work fine! I am a novice at python. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This line works perfectly fine, the error comes from syntax error from preceding code.